# Reverse engineering a GET request parameter

Tags: http, get

I'm trying to imitate a GET request for some website. I used google chrome debug to find out what parameters are being sent, which headers and such.

Some parameters could be retrieved by looking through the html code but there is one parameter that I cannot find back. I tried searching through the html code, cookies but I just couldn't find it.

I suspect it may be stored in some javascript object but that is just a wild guess.

So my question is: what would you do to find out where this parameter comes from.

Comment: Are you saying that you can see the value in the GET url, but you can't figure how the page decides what value to put there? Or are you saying that the server seems to be using some other value (a session variable, for example) that appears nowhere in the GET packet?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET request parameters are passed in query string, so you just can just take a look at resulting request URL.

Cookies are passed in HTTP request headers; you can use browser developer tools (Chrome DevTools / Firebug / IE Developer Tools) to look at request headers.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer from @Kel:

Note that if the GET was badly designed (really badly), some parameters may be in the body of the request, which you can also inspect via Firebug, Chrome Developer, basically pressing F12 any most browsers.